# System.Web.UI.UserControl Does not have a property named ItemTemplate

Tags: asp.net

While trying to create a templated web user control, I am facing a problem that System.Web.UI.UserControl does not have a property named ItemTemplate.

How can I resolve it?

Ascx file code is:

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MyTemplatedControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="MyTemplatedControl" %>
<asp:Placeholder runat="server" ID="ph1" />
```

.ascx.cs file code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;

using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;


public partial class MyTemplatedControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    private ITemplate itemTemplate = null;
    private ITemplate alternatingItemTemplate = null;
    [TemplateContainer(typeof(ItemContainer))]
    public ITemplate ItemTemplate
    { 
        get{return itemTemplate;}
        set { itemTemplate = value; }
    }
    public ITemplate AlternatingItemTemplate 
    {
        get { return alternatingItemTemplate; }
        set { alternatingItemTemplate = value; }
    }
    private bool isOdd(int i)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
    void Page_init()
    {
        String[] student = { "sam", "ram", "geet", "rosy", "linda", "vandana" };
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            ItemContainer container = new ItemContainer(student[i]);
            if (isOdd(i))
            {
                alternatingItemTemplate.InstantiateIn(container);
            }
            else
            {
                itemTemplate.InstantiateIn(container);
            }
            this.ph1.Controls.Add(container);
        }

        }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
public class ItemContainer : Control, System.Web.UI.INamingContainer
{
 private String _s_name;
    internal ItemContainer(String name)
    {
        _s_name = name;
    }
    public String name 
    {
        get { return _s_name; }
    }
}
```

.aspx file code is:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<%@ Register src="~/MyTemplatedControl.ascx" TagName="MyTemplatedControl" TagPrefix="uc1" %>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Test page for Templated User Control</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <uc1:MyTemplatedControl runat="server" ID="MyTemplatedControl">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <font color="blue">
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label2" Text='<%#Container.name%>' />
    </font>
    <hr />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <font color="green">
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Text='<%#Container.name%>' />
    </font>
    <hr />
    </AlternatingItemTemplate> 

    </uc1:MyTemplatedControl>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

.aspx.cs file code is this:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataBind();

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe you can do this with user controls. At least when I was creating controls, you needed to use an actual server control. User controls are much more limited, in return for the freedom to compose them out of markup.

Comment: i am a student and biginer. will u plz suggest me , wat to do???

Comment: Use `System.Web.UI.Control` as your base class. Why are you creating controls if you are a beginner? That's not a beginner task.

Comment: simply bcz it is given into my practice work book.i am just  starting it.

Comment: sir, it is still giving an error that System.Web.UI.control does not contain definition of name in line 1 of .aspx page.

Comment: It certainly used to be the case that you can't do this sort of thing with user controls. Please see "[Developing Custom ASP.NET Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt27tfhy.aspx)" for how to create custom server controls. It's not the sort of thing that a beginner should be doing.